# How do I make a button persist after the bot is restarted? discord.js

Tags: discord.js

So, I'm making a bot, and I'm working on a ticket system, and currently I want it to be a `Press to create` type deal, where users press a button in a channel, and the bot creates a channel, but when I make the embed send with the button, then restart the bot, the button no longer works. So, my question is, how do I make a button persist even after the bot is restarted?

Comment: It would be helpful if you included the relevant code that isn't working for you in your question, so we can modify it to do what you're asking. StackOverflow is not a code-writing service; provide the relevant parts of your current code so we don't have to write something from scratch. As for the answer to your question, an extremely simple `interactionCreate` event handler can do this; thus, providing your code is very relevant to understand what you are doing that isn't working for you.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you include the code or the errors you get when running the said code.

From what I have right now, I would recommend saving the said button id, and when the bot receives button interaction, check if the interaction comes from the same id. If so => execute code.